# Open activity when listview Item is clicked?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to built this app which simple consist of a ListView and different other activities that will be called when an item from the view is clicked. I want to when i pressed `string Rumus Ekonomi` it will open `RumusEkonomi.class` but when I click `string Rumus Ekonomi`, it force closes.

here the code:

public class Beranda extends ListActivity
{
    String [] items =  { "Rumus Ekonomi", "Rumus Manajemen", "Rumus Akutansi" };

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.beranda_layout);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    if (position == 0) 
    {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, RumusEkonomi.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
    else if (position == 1) 
    {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, RumusManajemen.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
    }
    else if (position == 2) 
    {
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, RumusAkutansi.class);
        startActivity(intent3);
    } 
}}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

*UPDATE*

Here is code manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rumus"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.rumus.Rumus"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
   </activity>
   <activity android:name=".Beranda" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RumusEkonomi"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >    
    </activity> 
</application>
</manifest>
```

First i declare `<intent-filter>` to `android:name="com.example.rumus.Rumus"` but when i click, it forces closes. so i move the `<intent-filter>` to `<activity android:name=".Beranda"` but it forces closes too

Answer (score 0):

Use this where you are using intent:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourClassName.class);  //Change here use getApplicationContext()
startActivity(intent1);
```

Instead of this:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, YourClassName.class);
startActivity(intent1);
```

Comment: I change what you say, but when I click it, it still forced to close.

Comment: Can you post your log.

Comment: [link] (http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-g6Hrp5Bz7RE/VXPnjtI2oMI/AAAAAAAAAMA/h96i3GNUZwU/s1600/logchat.png)

Comment: Check if you have declared your Activity in Manifest or not

Comment: i'd declared my Activity in Manifest

Comment: no, i'm done declared the activity in my manifest `<activity android:name=".Beranda" 
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
       
       </activity>`

Comment: Beranda is your first activity which you want to launch

Comment: You haven't declared all your activities in your manifest thats why you are getting error

Comment: Just add all entries of activities into your manifest and your good to go

Comment: yes, i've add all entries of activities but still error

Comment: What you dont know your log showing Exception for unable to instantiate Activity so as i suggest earlier just add entries of all activities in manifest

Comment: try to clean tour project and restart eclipce

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide an appropriate context to your Intents. Change your `onListItemClick()` block to the following

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

if (position == 0) {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Beranda.this, RumusEkonomi.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
}
else if (position == 1) {
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Beranda.this, RumusManajemen.class);
    startActivity(intent2);
}
else if (position == 2) {
    Intent intent3 = new Intent(Beranda.this, RumusAkutansi.class);
    startActivity(intent3);
} 
}
```

Edit: Change your Manifest file to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.rumus"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   <activity android:name=".Beranda" 
             android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <activity
        android:name=".RumusEkonomi"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >    
   </activity> 
   <activity
        android:name=".RumusManajemen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
   </activity>
   <activity
        android:name=".RumusAkutansi"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
   </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: In your beranda_layout file, is the id of the ListView set to `android:id="@android:id/list"` ?

Comment: yes i have set the ListView to android:id="@android:id/list"

Comment: Have you declared your other activities in your Manifest file?

Comment: [link] (http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-1yIwjU_LZj4/VXP9FF9e4lI/AAAAAAAAAMQ/gCaj6yx8W9w/s1600/log2.png)

Comment: Seems error generates into  RumusEkonomi.class. Can you please post RumusEkonomi.class code with respected layout file. After i will help you to investigate the error.

Comment: What does your RumusEkonomi.Activity look like? Update your post with it. Also, include it's layout.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using android:id="@android:id/list" for your list view in beranda_layout.